# Doctrine left join where joined table is null shows results

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

the goal of this query is to show records from table orders that don't have any shipments created yet. Here is how it should be done in SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN orders_shipments shipments ON orders.trx_id = shipments.trx_id
WHERE shipments.shipment_id IS NULL 
AND orders.purchase_date IS NOT NULL 
AND orders.fulfillment_channel = 'MFN';
```

The following query shows 0 results. Vs the following:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('orders');
        $qb->select('orders, shipments')
        ->leftjoin('orders.shipments', 'shipments')
        ->Where('shipments.id IS NULL')
        ->ANDWhere('orders.purchaseDate IS NOT NULL')
        ->ANDWhere('orders.fulfillmentChannel = :a')->setParameter('a', 'MFN');;
        $results = $qb->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
        return $results;
```

Does show results. Why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: Where, ANDWhere is capitalized wrong, but maybe thats not the problem.

Comment: what is the output of `echo  $qb->getQuery();`

Comment: -_dql: "SELECT orders, shipments FROM OrderBundle\Entity\Orders orders LEFT JOIN orders.shipments shipments WHERE shipments.id IS NULL AND orders.purchaseDate IS NOT NULL AND orders.fulfillmentChannel = :a"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure why but I had to use GROUP and HAVING to get it to work:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('orders');
        $qb->select('orders, shipments')
        ->leftjoin('orders.shipments', 'shipments')
        ->Where('shipments.id IS NULL')
        ->ANDWhere('orders.purchaseDate IS NOT NULL')
        ->ANDWhere('orders.fulfillmentChannel = :a')->setParameter('a', 'MFN')
        ->GroupBy('orders.id')
        ->having('count(shipments) = 0');
        $results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```